# Javascript Midpoint Line Drawing Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, line

I'm drawing a line in  javascript using the Midpoint Algorithm Line Drawing.
When the line is in a descent trajectory, it computes the wrong values.
Can somebody help me?

data input
//midline(1,6,8,4);

```
function midline(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
  /* Using midpoint algorithm for lines. */
  const dx = x1 - x0;
  const dy = y1 - y0;
  var d = 2 * dy - dx;
  const incrE = 2 * dy;
  const incrNE = 2 * (dy - dx);
  var x = x0;
  var y = y0;

  var output = [];

  //listeners
  console.log("dy = ", dy, "dx = ", dx);
  console.log("d = ", d);
  console.log("incrE = ", incrE);
  console.log("incrNE = ", incrNE);
  console.log("----------------------------------");

  while (x <= x1) {
    // if not the last x
    console.log("x = ", x, " y = ", y);
    output.push([x,y]);


    if (d <= 0) {
      console.log("E");

      d = d + incrE;
      x++;
    } else {
      console.log("NE");

      d = d + incrNE;
      x++;
      y++;
    }
  }
  console.table(output);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Based on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mid-point-line-generation-algorithm/, it appears that the Mid Point Line Drawing algorithm is suited for the first quadrant and that "reflection" techniques have to be used to calculate the line for the other quadrants.  Seems like that might be your issue, as I don't see checks in your code to ensure or adjust for cases when the following does not hold:  x0 < x1 && y0 < y1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If per my comment the Mid Point Line Drawing algorithm is only suited for the first quadrant, that is...

```
 x0 < x1 and y0 < y1
```

...must hold true, then adjustments are required if x1 < x0 or y1 < y0.

Taking the case presented (1,6) - (8,4), this is a downward slope because y1 < y0 (ie, 4 < 6 ).  To make this a workable case for the Mid Point Line Drawing algorithm, you can simply negate the y values, in which case y0 < y1 will then hold true.  Of course, when capturing the results, the values need to then be adjusted by multiplying by -1 again.  So, suggest wedging in the following before putting x0, y0, x1, and y1 to use...

```
let xReflect = 1;
if ( x1 < x0 ) {
    x0 = -x0;
    x1 = -x1;
    xReflect = -1;
}

let yReflect = 1;
if ( y1 < y0 ) {
    y0 = -y0;
    y1 = -y1;
    yReflect = -1;
}
```

...and then, when pushing the output to the array, you will need to perform the following...

```
output.push( [ x * xReflect, y * yReflect ] );
```

Hope this helps.